# How to get a SHIFT-selection with pickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I am wondering if it is possible to "fake" a SHIFT-selection or drag-selection with `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets`?

Basically in the example below I would like to select all letters from A to G with 2 mouse-clicks, by clicking on A, then with SHIFT and clicking G, all elements between get selected.

There is already a [github-issue](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/199) for that purpose, but I was wondering if its possible to fake it with some JavaScript?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("asd", label = "How to select from-to with SHIFT:",
              choices = LETTERS[1:10], multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I came up with a solution by editing the underlying JS-library. There is a [PR](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/pull/228) now if someone is interested in testing/using it